# Jquery - Calendar widget to pick weeks

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

Do we have any available calendar widgets in jquery/javascript which helps us to select a week rather than dates.

My application has 2 dropdowns, From week and To week.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that you need:

```
 $('#weeklyDatePicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
      var value = $("#weeklyDatePicker").val();
      var firstDate = moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(0).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
      var lastDate =  moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(6).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
      $("#weeklyDatePicker").val(firstDate + " - " + lastDate);
  });
```

for refrence you can check this link 
https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/9usq3enn/

This may help you

Comment: $.datepicker.iso8601Week(date);  you can use this for getting week number.